# jQuery multiple selected selector creating ul list with selections

Tags: jquery

this might sound silly for a few, but I would like to know how you can create html code out of multiple selection lists using jQuery.

I tried using the default code found in the jQuery site:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>selected demo</title>
        <style>
            div {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
            <option>Flowers</option>
            <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
            <option>Trees</option>
            <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>
            <option>Grass</option>
            <option>Dirt</option>
        </select>
        <div></div>
        <script>
            $("select").change(function() {
                var str = "";
                $("select option:selected").each(function() {
                    str += $(this).text() + " ";
                });
                $("div").text(str);
            }).trigger("change");
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

How can you create `<li></li>` objects out of your selection? Sorry, I am relatively new to the jquery code, but couldn't figure it out, I am sure it's something easy.

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/8PTJe/

Comment: And now the question changed to LI elements, and I suppose you just create LI elements then -> http://jsfiddle.net/8PTJe/1/

Comment: the code is taken straight from the jquery website.

Answer (score 3):

just add `<ul></ul>` next of your select tag ( remove div tag )
and change your code to this

```
$("select").change(function() {
                var str = "";
                $("select option:selected").each(function() {
                    str += "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
                });
                $("ul").html(str);
            }).trigger("change");
```